# Where to place gui item code

Tags: java, swing

I am starting a new GUI project, and I am wondering where is the best place to put item code, such as a button, text field or something else? I don't think that the best place for the code is in the main class, because it seems like that would be too much code for one file and harder to manage. This is how I usually do it (The all in one file way).

```
package apollo;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Apollo{

    protected JFrame frame = new JFrame("Apollo");

    public Apollo(){
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        this.buildLayout();
        frame.revalidate();
    }

    protected void buildLayout(){
        JTextField txt = new JTextField(30);
        frame.add(txt);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Submit");
        frame.add(btn);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Apollo a = new Apollo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this article an how to put together a Swing GUI will help.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=349

Comment: Another example for : [MVC - Model View Controller Pattern](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/07/07/genericmvc.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main class should typically have nothing but a main method.

That main method should create a class which handles initializing your GUI.

For other UI components, if you reuse them, or their code is large, the component needs its own class.

If you'll never reuse the component, and its code is small, it doesn't need its own class.

Comment: +1 for the first part of your answer. -1 for using UI-designer advice.

Comment: Professionals I know are split on this one, as code dependent on a code generator is dependent on that generator being updated appropriately. Many instead use their own well honed libraries. Regardless, I agree with many here that until the student understands the Swing library, they should hand-code their code in order to gain an understanding since a code generator will hide the details and could hinder understanding. Once achieved, then sure use code-generation as desired.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels very good point. Writing UI code in college has helped me in my career. Sometimes UI generators produce unexpected output, how can you fix that if you don't understand the code it produces? Editing answer.

Comment: What about each item? should they have their own class too?

Comment: Each frame should have its own class.

Comment: or perhaps better: each separate *view* should have its own class. Often multiple views are combined into one GUI.

Comment: Right. If you will reuse the view, or if the view's code is large, it needs its own class.  If you'll never reuse the view, and its code is small, put it in a frame.